# git pull and clone failed; The remote end hung up unexpectedly RPC failed;

Tags: windows, git

Hi I wanted to pull a project which I was working on it about a month ago. After one month I wanted to get the latest updates of the project with git pull but it won't work and had this error:

```
The remote end hung up unexpectedly RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Then I wanted to clone this project. So I get the link and clone it with intellij but it did not work again and the error was the same as before.

What should I do???

P.S: my OS is windows 64-bit

Solved: the problem was from the SSH Key. I set SSH Key for the repository and it works fine right now.

Comment: And can you verify that the remote repository still exists?

Comment: yeah i'm sure about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: the problem was from the SSH Key. I set SSH Key for the repository and it works fine right now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use following command
Try this one first

`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

and then run this one

`$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git`

after that clone your project.
Your problem should be resolved.

Comment: Have you tried to clone it with the different project name?

Comment: Please check once more that, if you have the correct privilege on the repository.

Comment: I tried it but the error still remains same.(the name of the project does not have any relation to these things!)

Comment: On which website your repository is available?
Try to check with the privilege of your username.

Comment: The problem Solved with SSH key for the repository

Comment: congratulations then.
Please answer your question to help others to resolve this issue.